# Debug C++ in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

None of the directions in VSCode guide work.
What is the right config to be able to step through C++ code on VSCode in MacOS?

I followed the directions line by line and I am never able to reproduce what VSCode has [documented](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

When I chose build and debug file and place a breakpoint in code, it never stops at breakpoint. When I hover over breakpoint, it shows

> "Module Containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the
> breakpoint address could not be obtained"

None of the debug buttons on top actually do anything:
[image: debug screenshot]

My tasks.json file is configured as below(same as VSCode documentation)

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Not enough details. Based on your question, I understand that you did... something... and it did not result in stopping on your break point. Since I do not know what you did, I have no way to determine whether or not an answer is just advising you to do what you already did.

Comment: @JaMiT I added details. ON VSCode website it says if you have questions ask in StackOverflow. so I thought they have people here monitoring VSCode questions.

Comment: *"I thought they have people here monitoring VSCode questions."* -- they might, but think of them as a rather small part of your potential audience.

Comment: Can you compile and run code?

Comment: @bolov yes I can